# Material ui Snackbar show only once and doesn't reopen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Snackbar component from the Material-UI framework but I can't make it work correctly because the Snackbar shows only the first time, from the second message the Snackbar remain closed.

Here is the code I used to wrap the Snackbar:

```
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Notification({ message }) {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(message);

    return (
        <Snackbar
            key={Math.random()}
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'center'
            }}
            open={value ? true : false}
            autoHideDuration={5000}
            message={value}
            onClose={() => { console.log('snackbar closed'); setValue('') }}
        />
    )
};
```

I use this component to show the result when the user submit a form. For example when the submit is succesful the message 'operation completed' is shown, but if the server doesn't validate the submission a message error is shown. Here is the code:

```
function InnerForm({ mode, detail, entity }) {

  const isCreateMode = mode === 'create';
  const schema = createSchema(entity);

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
    setValue
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: detail,
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const [submitResponse, setSubmitResponse] = useState();

  const onSubmit = async data => {

    const operation = isCreateMode ?
      entity.Client.create(data) :
      entity.Client.update(data);

    const response = await operation;

    setSubmitResponse(response);
    console.log(response);

    if (response.success) {

      if (isCreateMode) {
        const autoField = entity.Fields.find(({ auto }) => auto);

        if (autoField) {
          setValue(autoField.id, response.content[autoField.id]);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {
        submitResponse ?
          submitResponse.success ?
            <Notification message='operation completed' /> :
            submitResponse.problem ?
              <Notification message={submitResponse.problem} /> :
              <Notification message='operation failed' />
          : null
      }
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {
          entity.Fields.map(field => {
            const props = {
              control,
              id: field.id,
              label: field.label,
              error: errors[field.id]?.message,
              multiline: field.type === 'text',
              loadOptions: field.loadOptions,
              getOptionLabel: field.getOptionLabel,
              readonly: submitResponse?.success || field.auto || (field.key && !isCreateMode)
            };

            const Component =
              field.type === 'string' ? TextInput :
                field.type === 'datetime' ? DatetimeInput :
                  field.type === 'text' ? TextInput :
                    field.type === 'entity' ? SelectInput :
                      field.type === 'bool' ? CheckboxInput :
                        TextInput;

            return <Component {...props} />
          })
        }

        <SubmitButton isCreateMode={mode === 'create'} readonly={submitResponse?.success} />
      </form>
    </>
```

The test I do is the following:

- First, I compile the form with invalid data and execute the submit => **Ok, the snackbar appear with an error message**.
- Second, I correct the data and execute a new submit => **The submit is succesful, but the success message is not shown**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like you're updating `state` once it receives new `props`, only initializing the `state` the first time it's created.

You could try to update `state` when it's called a second time.

You could also keep the `open` state inside the `InnerForm` component, and add  a callback function as a parameter to `Notification` that would be called in `onClose` that would update the state of the `Snackbar` inside `InnerForm`

Example of the second suggestion:

In `InnerForm`

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [message, setMessage] = useState(message);

const callback = () => {
    setValue(false)
}

// In render() you need to add this line.
<Notification message={message} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={callback}/>
```

In `Notification`

```
export default function Notification({ message, isOpen, onClose }) {

return (
    <Snackbar
        key={Math.random()}
        anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'center'
        }}
        open={isOpen}
        autoHideDuration={5000}
        message={message}
        onClose={onClose}
    />
)
};
```

Finally, you just have to update `message` and `isOpen` in `InnerForm` where you currently call the `Notification` function

Comment: Thanks for the help, you solved my problem. Then, a component doesn't reset its state when props changes?

Comment: Components do not automatically update state when receiving new props. The reason you got your message inside state was because state is being initialised to the value of message during the first render.

I believe this is the way to update props using hooks: `useEffect(() => {
    setValue(message)
  }, [message]);`.  If you prefer you could use your code with this change. Though, I personally think that it makes more sense for the parent component `InnerForm` to decide when the `Notification` should be open, like my example in the answer above.